# preventing sql injection in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

If user input is inserting without modification from `SQL query`, then the application becomes vulnerable to `SQL injection`, like in the following example:

```
$unsafe_variable = $_POST['user_input']; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES ('$unsafe_variable')");
```

That's because the user can input something like value `'); DROP TABLE table;--,` and the query becomes:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES('value'); DROP TABLE table;--')
```

What can be done to prevent this from happening?

Comment: what's the point of duplicating a well-answered question??

Comment: You just copied the whole question, literally — that's wrong. 
The question you copied has >20 answers, some of them are several pages long and cover the topic in details. If that isn't enough, I recommend you to get books on PHP and SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *extensive* information through simple Google searches that can guide you in the right direction. To start though:

**DON'T USE MYSQL_* FUNCTIONS** These are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and will generate warnings. They are *not even remotely good practice for modern web development*.

**USE A DATABASE LIBRARY INSTEAD** like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). There's plenty of tutorials to get you started and most importantly these libraries ***take care of SQL injection for you***. So use them!